# How do I display Taxonomy image on Taxonomy page and child page

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

Drupal 7 | Views 3

I have a parent Taxonomy term that has a Taxonomy image.  I have nodes belonging to the taxonomy term.  My goal is simple, but apparently hard to achieve.

1. I want to be able to display the taxanomy term page with the taxaomny term image as the header image of that page.
2. I then want to display that same taxanomy image on the child pages.  (I guess another way to say it, I want to display the parent term image on the child pages as a header image.)

I have been playing around with multiple setting on the taxomny page view.  And I can't seem to achieve it!

I have worked about 5 hours trying to achieve this and the site is due Thursday.  Somebody please help me out here.  I am about to go crazy!!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display taxonomy field in node display](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1770/display-taxonomy-field-in-node-display)

Comment: May be it will help http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_image

Comment: Check this also you will get idea http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32104/attach-image-to-taxonomy-term